# Laravel 5.3 + Passport: always unauthenticated error

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I'm always receiving "Unauthenticated error" when using Passport in my current project. That's what I did the lasts 3 days:

- Install and configure Passport (as docs says)
- Request a token (password grant token) with Postman
- Request a protected route (auth:api middleware) with the token
- Get 
  `{ "error": "Unauthenticated." }`
- Search and search and research
- Get 
  `{ "error": "Unauthenticated." }`

Then, I've installed a fresh L5.3 and a fresh DB and works fine. Even with my current DB!

I've tried all the solutions that I found without success ...

Can anyone help me? Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: i guess you send token as authorization parameter in header according to documents about OAuth , but apache block this parameter and passport middleware cant authenticate your request, change authentication name to other thing such as token or key or everything except authorization. be successful

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you and looked everywhere to find a solution.

It appeared to be Apache's fault in my case. Apache was deleting the header "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_HERE" so the auth:api wouldn't work as expected (getting 401 unauthorized).

We ended up trying adding to our .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)

RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

And it magically worked.

I really hope it helps, we spent a whole day trying many solutions, this is the one that worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

Which `grant_type` have you used to generate this token?

Possible resolutions are as follows

1: If you are using client credentials to generate your access_token, you have to turn on client_credentials, middleware as follows.

1.1 Add to the routeMiddleware in \App\Http\Kernel.php

```
'client_credentials'     => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class,
```

1.2 Use 'client_credentials' middleware in your route too.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1','middleware' => 'client_credentials'], function () {

    // Your routes here

});
```

2: For Grant Type Password

2.1 : Create a Password Grant Client

php artisan passport:client --password

2.2 : Request A token with following header fields

```
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => 'client-id',
    'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
    'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
    'password' => 'my-password',
```

End point /oauth/token

The token you get now should give you access to your api.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was an omision, I'm building a GraphQL api and in the middleware line at the configuration file "graphql.php" I put

```
'middleware' => ['auth'],
```

when the correct way is:

```
'middleware' => ['auth:api'],
```

Answer (score 0):

check your user model has

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

instead of

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

and used HasApiTokens as a trait;